# Finding vector with most number of zero-coordinates.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of $N$ orthogonal vectors (over $\mathbb{C}$) For some $c : N \mod c = 0$, how would I go about choosing $c$ vectors from the set such that the span of the $c$ vectors contains the vector with the least number of zeros (excluding the zero vector). I believe there is a similar question on MSE, but there are no references mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You're saying that $c$ divides $N$, and you need $c$ vectors?  Is it important that these two things are the same?

Comment: @rschweib Sorry, I don't exactly follow your comment. The constraint $c \mod N$ is not critical and can be dropped if it is any consolation. I require $c$ vectors to be output from the ($N$ element) set of vectors such that in the span of those $c$ vectors lies the max-$0$ vector ($c \ne N$).

Comment: That is helpful. Also, do you intend the vectors to be over the field $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @rschweib I should have mentioned that. They are over $\mathbb{C}$.